# Title tag won't change in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new on using Wordpress, but I understand php code.

I have a 'child' functions.php, a function to echo out category name based on the parameter (`catid`) on the url (www.example.com/?catid=123). The category name is retrieved from MySQL database, so inside the child-function is just a list of SQL syntax.

Now, I can use the function properly (echo it out with some `if..else` statement) inside my page.php (the content). But it won't work on my header.php and apparently only on `<title>` tag. I mean, if I just randomly echo out in any `<div>` of my header.php, it works just fine. But when I tried to echo it out inside title, so something like this

```
<?php
   if(!isset($_GET['catid'])) { 
      $title= 'use default title set from wp dashboard(wp_title())';
   } else { 
      $title= 'my own title based on categoryid';
   }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="<?php language_attributes(); ?>" />
   <head>
      <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
      <title> <?php echo $title; ?> </title>
 //the rest of the header code here
```

I copied original page.php (edit: I mean header.php) from the 'parent' and pasted it into 'child' folder. I edit the code which is in 'child' folder (let's just called it child-page.php (typo, it's child-header.php).

What did I do wrong? I can't display it on title tag. The page title will display the title based on `wp_title()` (as we set from dashboard) in fact, not even echoing out the `$title` I set.

Comment: Are you changing this for the selected theme or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, for the selected theme.

Comment: Just remove `if..else` and only check `$title= 'my own title based on categoryid';` this working or not?

Comment: It works for u? what are u getting now?

Comment: hi, I tried it. but no luck. It still displays wp_title() (the one we set from dashboard). The page that I should be editing is the child's header.php right?

Comment: Make sure that the title tag that you are definging is the only title tag in the header. Also make sure the file you are editing is the actual file that is controls the page you are seeing in your browser.

Write a string before the <!DOCTYPE html> line to check that you are editing the correct file.

Comment: hi yes, I tried to echo random word BEFORE the doctype, and it echoes out just fine on browser...and I tried to echo static stuff directly inside <title></php echo 'test';?></title> also returns the default (as per wp_title())...

Comment: @Ovidiu hi so I found out that on parent-functions.php there is a function setting up the title. I have modified it (in child-function.php) and have added if(!function_exists) to the parent-functions.php. I echo out before    <!doctype> 
    <?php echo wp_title() ?>

I can see it echoes "my custom title", but then I use the same method inside    <title>, it doesn't work....

Comment: add:
I add something dummy like <title>testing <?php echo $title;?></title>
And run it, the title still only shows the page title set from the dashboard! 
I even tried to use the parent theme, and edit it as the above, and it still won't show the additional 'testing' wordings!

Comment: then, it must be because the parent functions file rewrites the title using the wp_title hook, you should hook a function of your own in the child theme. You can get the example from twentytwelve or twentyeleven, if I remember correctly, both themes hook into wp_title.